# CodeIgniter: Accessing array values using set_value()

Tags: php, codeigniter

New to CodeIgniter, apologies this is simple stuff. I have a controller with an array which holds an array of values and associative fields.

**Controller**

```
$tests = array( "ID" => "1", "Fcilty_typ" => "MO");
```

**View**

```
 <input type="text" name="Fcilty_typ" value="<?php echo set_value('Fcilty_typ','Fcilty_typ')?>"/>
```

How can I manipulate the array in the controller so it's key=>values are accessible in the view, within the set_vaue(); function.

Comment: Did you pass the array into the view from the controller?

Comment: The array $tests is accessible in the view. I haven't passed in the call to the view though.

Comment: Can you add your controller code related to this

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="Fcilty_typ" value="<?php echo set_value('Fcilty_typ',$tests['Fcilty_typ']) ?>"/>
```

you could also do something like this with ci form helper.

```
$form_fcilty = array(
              'name'        => 'Fcilty_typ',
              'id'          => 'Fcilty_typ',
              'value'       => $tests['Fcilty_typ'],
              'maxlength'   => '100',
              'size'        => '50',
            );

echo form_input($form_fcilty);
```

that way you don't have to mix too much html and php to create the form. note you can also do the form_input array with set_value() if you need to show the submitted form value again after a validation fail.